# Printing on Bixolon SPP-R410 - C#

Tags: c#, printing, bixolon-printer

I have a question about the print length on the printer Bixolon SPP-R410.
I developed the code in C# for printing using their SDK, but I'm having trouble adjusting the length of the print on the paper.

I set the area to be printed using the code below, but when i have more text to print and set the height parameter above 3000 the printer doesn't accept it and prints the text up to about 2600.

```
BxlPrint.SetPrintAreaInPM(0, 0, 879, 3000);
```

How can i set it to print longer texts than 3000 height?

Note: the code was developed for the Windows operating system.

I tried with changes to the printer driver, various changes in the code but to no avail.

Comment: Which SDK are you using from C#?

Comment: I'm using the Windows SDK from their site https://www.bixolon.com/download_view.php?idx=15#download-anchor04
Within the bxl dll file they have methods that can be called in C# and printed.

Comment: The command manual explains that the page height is limited to 300mm (or 2400 dots where there are 8/mm or 203/in). I don't think you are supposed to use Page Mode if you want to print something really long - you should use standard mode and just drop into Page Mode for areas where you need to be able to print out of order.

Comment: I understand, but in this case I print the invoice and because of the positioning of the text on the x and y axis, and I need to use Page Mode the positioning to work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

BxlPrint.SetVerticalPositionInPM(60);
BxlPrint.SetHorizontalPositionInPM(0);
BxlPrint.PrintText("text", BxlPrint.BXL_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, BxlPrint.BXL_FT_FONTB, BxlPrint.BXL_TS_1WIDTH | BxlPrint.BXL_TS_1HEIGHT);

Comment: If you must use Page Mode, why not setup as much Page Areas you need, then print in chunks? In Standard Mode, I think you could just use `BxlPrint.LifeFeed(2);` to move down 60 dots?

Comment: I just did that. Since i get one DataTable for the items on the invoice, i split it into several DataTables with the number of items that can be printed on one page, and then print one DataTable  at a time defining the PageArea for each.
Thanks for your help @NetMage.